# Set time to reload parent window after form closes

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a drop-down list for categories. I created a popup for new category. When I hit submit the form, a new category is stored in a DB table, which will show on the drop-down list for categories. However, when I submit the form, it closes and reload so quick that the new category is not inserted into the DB table yet. How do I set 5 seconds to reload the parent page after the popup window closes.

My code:

```
function reloadIt() {
opener.location.reload(true);
self.close();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: [It sounds like you're looking for `setTimeout` function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: I do not know if this is what you need but you can do this: setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);

Comment: `setInterval` runs a function *every* n seconds.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setTimeout` to "schedule" a function for later:

`setTimeout(() => { /*...*/ }, 5000);`

edit:

Here's a more fleshed out version, sans arrow syntax:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  opener.location.reload(true);
  self.close();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: No, it's the exact opposite. Or I'm going crazy. Googling to determine sanity-state. *(edit: Was responding to now-deleted comment.)*

Comment: No, you're right @shabs, this is exactly what the asker was looking for.

Comment: @JennyTran, replace "`/*...*/`" with the logic you want to execute. Keep in mind that arrow syntax requires ES6 support or transpilation.

Comment: I tried that. When I clicked the popup window and started filling out the form, it closed just 5 seconds even though I have not submitted it. I like to submit the form by myself, then, it closes popup, then the parent refresh to get updated info after 5 seconds.

Comment: Move the snippet into your submit handler.

Answer (score 1):

```
function reloadIt() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        opener.location.reload(true);
        self.close();
    }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: It didn't close the form nor refresh the parent page.